# Track schema growth in oracle

Tags: oracle, schema

I am trying to track the growth of one particular schema in Oracle Database. For example, how much space was used by a particular schema month by month for last six months or so(also forecast for a month, don't know if this is possible at all). I used dba_segments, dba_object and all_tables so far, any inputs to get to the data I am looking for will be very helpful.
Also, I am trying clean-up a particular Schema so that it does not run into space issues. Any thoughts on how to free up  schema space this will be helpful too. My idea is to archive and drop extra table partitions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't delete tables, an option to shrink them is to use and alter command and move them to a new tablespace.

```
alter table xxx move tablespace newtablespacename
```

After you have moved all of the objects out of the original tablespace, you can drop it.

Your can specify all the table storage parameters with the move tablespace command, so you can change the storage parameters if you so choose.